# How to create JSON Object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have JSON like this :

```
{
   "success":true,
   "data":[
      {
         "id": 1,
         "markname":"nama_penduduk",
         "markvalue":"Vin Diesel"
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "markname":"umur_penduduk",
         "markvalue":"20 Tahun"
      },
      {
         "id": 3,
         "markname":"keperluan_membuat_surat",
         "markvalue":"Untuk uji coba surat"
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to create a JSON like this :

```
const newJSON = {
    nama_penduduk: 'Vin Diesel',
    umur_penduduk: '20 Tahun',
    keperluan_membuat_surat: 'Untuk uji coba surat'
};
```

Code :

```
dataResult.map((value) => {
  const markName = value.markname;
  const markValue = value.markvalue;

  res.status(200).json({
      markName: markValue
  });
});
```

Suppose I don't know how many data I have, how do I create this object in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const dataResult = [{
    "id": 1,
    "markname": "nama_penduduk",
    "markvalue": "Vin Diesel"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "markname": "umur_penduduk",
    "markvalue": "20 Tahun"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "markname": "keperluan_membuat_surat",
    "markvalue": "Untuk uji coba surat"
  }
]

const newJSON = dataResult.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.markname] = cur.markvalue;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newJSON);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I should use FormData to modify the JSON

Answer (score 1):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const myObject = dataResult.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr[acc.markname] = acc.markvalue;

  return curr;
}, {});
```

So yeah, we add acc.markname on the returned object. Pretty self explanatory :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I should use FormData to modify the JSON